# Multiple cameras on Android

Tags: javascript, android, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

Why do some Android devices expose all physical cameras in `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, while other expose just one? The devices where I tested run on Android 10 or 11.

According to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera2/multi-camera), devices running on Android 9 or higher will support exposing all cameras.

I also tried using the Camera 2 API, but without any luck. All I get is two cameras, one front and one back. But my device has 3 back cameras.

Do you know why I cannot access all cameras with Android 11? Or how to enable exposing all of them?

Thanks,
Alin

Comment: A vendor is not forced to expose all their camera hardware via the public apis : "With the inclusion of multi-camera support in the framework, Android best practices strongly recommend that phone manufacturers expose a logical camera for all physical cameras facing the same direction" - Android 9+ simply states "private apis", i.e apis that don't exist in the normal public sdk. Yet vendors can easily get around this with their own sdk-addons to create api's (this is the correct way vendors can add their own apis to a build that they can access in apps via a stubbed sdk-addon jar).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @MarkKeen. What's the preferred solution to access those cameras from Android? Ultimately I want to get the image in some javascript code.